# Is it possible to change the collapse table displayed in popuptemplate in ArcGIS API?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I would like to add another field to the collapsed view that appears on clicking a CSVLayer element when multiple items are present in that particular location.

Currently, its shown like this,

[image]

I want to add another column to this table. Now only the title of the PopupTemplate is shown.

Comment: Can you share an example

Answer (score 2):

I don't think adding an additional column is possible. The list however uses the [`PopupTemplate.title`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-PopupTemplate.html#title) property so you can show additional information by adding it to the title:

```
var popupTemplate = csvLayer.createPopupTemplate();

// Dynamic popup title
popupTemplate.title = function(feature) {
  return "Document basic info: " + feature.graphic.attributes["DocumentId"];
}

csvLayer.popupTemplate = popupTemplate;
```

See the following CodePen for a running version: https://codepen.io/arnofiva/pen/15438955c0e95b65fbeec1350c72204d

[image: Popup showing single item]

[image: Popup showing list of items]